# How to print values in one array in relation to the values in the other array

Tags: python, arrays, list

So I have 2 arrays

```
Arr_1=[a,b,c...]

Arr_2=[d,e,f..]
```

Now Arr_2 and its values are basically derived from performing some calculations on Arr_1.
Now Basically what I want to do is find out that first/minimum value of Arr_1 at which Arr_2's value is greater than a certain number.
Can anyone point out how to do that?

For example

```
Arr_1=[1,2,3,4]

Arr_2=[10,20,30,40]
```

So now I set the condition that Values in Arr_2 should be greater that 15.
And then I would like the desired output to be the first value of Arr_1 for which the corresponding value of Arr_2 satisfies this condition-i.e the output should be 2

Answer (score 1):

Based on your now edited question, try below, You can modify it to meet your need

```
list1 = [2,3,4,5,6]
list2 = [1,33,4,5,2]

def test(value, items1,items2):

    for x,y in zip(items1,items2):
        if y > value:
            print(f'array1 :{x} array2: {y}')
            return x #<-- breaks on once the is first condition is met

test(15,list1,list2)
```

output

```
# array1: 3 array2: 33
```

Comment: Hi. I'm not looking for this.So basically I want to compare the values in array 2 to a certain number, lets say any value >1. So for the values of array 2 greater that 1(the number), I want to print the values corresponding to array 1 i.e the values in array 1 used to derive the said values in array 2

Comment: Your request is not clear, you may need to edit your question  and show the desired output you want

Comment: Hi. I just edited that. Perhaps its now clear?

Comment: I have adjusted it now

Comment: Yep. This is exactly what I wanted and it works. Thanks for this, you're a real lifesaver!

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate through both lists at the same time with `zip` like this:

```
for a_val, b_val in zip(arr1, arr2):
  if (b_val > some_number):
    print('something')
```

If this isn't what you're looking for, a little more clarification on the problem you're trying to solve would help.

Comment: So basically I want to compare the values in array 2 to a certain number, lets say any value >1. So for the values of array 2 greater that 1, I want to print the values corresponding to array 1 i.e the values in array 1 used to derive the said values in array 2.

Comment: Hi. I just edited my query with more details.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then since the values in the second list are created based on some operation in the first, the indices of the values should be the same. You can use **enumerate** to get the indices. This should work:

```
Arr_1=[1,2,3,4]
Arr_2 = [10,20,30,40]
value = 15

for i, x in enumerate(Arr_2):
    if x > value:
       print(Arr_1[i])
       break
```

I have used the break statement since you mentioned you only need the first value that satisfies the condition.

Comment: Yep, this is exactly what I wanted. Thanks!